# AWS API Gateway call FROM Salesforce: Best practices for Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, salesforce, aws-api-gateway

I have a working AWS API Gateway invoke URL that will be called by Salesforce agents in SFDC. However, I need to add authentication and I am looking for best practice advice. Note: we don't want to authenticate/authorize individual agents, just that the invoke URL can only be accessed by a logged in SFDC agent.

This is a difficult topic to research as almost all of the documentation is about AWS > SFDC rather than SFDC > AWS which is what I am doing.

Anyway, [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html) lists several ways to add authentication to my AWS gateway and it seems like Resource Policies and IAM roles are the best way to authenticate, but SFDC is outside AWS. IP based resource policies would work but the ranges that we are provided periodically change.

Amazon Cognito would work if I wanted to authorize specific agents, but that is specifically not the requirement.

API keys and usage plans seem to be the best fit, but [AWS Docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html):

> Important
> Don't use API keys for authentication or authorization for your APIs. If you have multiple APIs in a usage plan, a user with a valid API key for one API in that usage plan can access all APIs in that usage plan.

But, since I do not have multiple APIs in a usage plan, would this be an ok solution?

Something else that I am overlooking?

---

**TLDR: is an API key/usage plan for a single api sufficient security?**

Comment: AWS: best practice is [temporary token via STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html) + [tying it to API Gateway via IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html). On Salesforce side, Named Credentials natively support [AWS STS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_awssig4_ext_cred.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think that IP whitelisting is a merger security constraint. Why? Because sometimes BGP is misconfigured and IP traffic is routed differently. IPs is just a number which is not authenticated and (it's difficult, yes) but these can be spoofed.

What you are searching for is a machine-to-machine authentication.

There are multiple options:

1. Temporary Access Tokens, oAuth, SAML, ...
2. mTLS
3. API Keys, Basic Auth, static JWT, ...

I've listed API Keys last, since these are static credentials which can easily leak and then re-used by an attacker.

mTLS is more difficult to implement, but not with API Gateway, as it's natively supported (but may be difficult for SFDC?). mTLS authenticates both the server and client via SSL/TLS certificates.

Temporary Access Tokens, oAuth, etc. need an additional third party which federate the authentication between the client parties.

It largely depends on what security requirements your company has and which type of security is needed for the data transmitted (GPDR?). It is best to discuss this with the project/company architect which should be able to give guidance.

If all of that is not possible, I would try to go with mTLS.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response. From what I could find, Salesforce may only support mTLS for inbound calls. I will reach out to the security team to see if an API Key would be enough. Thanks again!